# Why does fontspec fontloader recompile an existing .luc file at each run of luatex?

Tags: luatex, luaotfload

Consider the following snippet:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\begin{document}
Test
\end{document}
```

Compiling with `lualatex`, one can read in the log file:

```
(compiling luc: /usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic/fonts/otl/lmroman10-regular.luc)
(load luc:/home/christophe/.texlive2016/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic/fonts/otl/lmroman10-regular.luc))
```

Why does the fontloader compile `lmroman10-regular.luc` instead of reading it directly it it exists?

Comment: it shouldn't do that (I just ran your example and it re-used the existing .luc)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Hum. Did you notice that the paths are different? A misconfiguration?

Comment: I can confirm (TL 2016) but for me it happens for other fonts as well with your minimal example.  On top of `lmroman10-regular.luc` also `lmromanslant10-regular.luc`, `lmroman10-italic.luc`, and `lmroman10-bold.luc` are recompiled each time.

Comment: Removing `~/.texlive2016` did not make it go way.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I'm seeing the same thing. My console output has (compiling luc: /
usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic/fonts/otl/lmroman10-regul
ar.luc)(load luc: /Users/herbs/Library/texlive/2016/texmf-var/luatex-cache/gene
ric/fonts/otl/lmroman10-regular.luc)) so it's loading the .luc in my personal texmf-var tree  but trying to compile one in the system texmf-var tree. That is owned by root so it never gets compiled. Should luaotfload first look in the personal texmf-var tree?

Comment: @HenriMenke and HerbSchulz Thank you both for taking the time to confirm the problem. Did you install texlive with root privileges (as I did)?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Should I report it as a TeXLive bug or as a luaotfload bug?

Comment: luaotfload in the first instance, I'd guess (although installing it with greater permissions than you use at run time might be a user error, it's a long time since I read the instructions:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle But what about GNU/Linux distribution vendors? They ship all their packages to be installed with superuser permission (so is TL). For users of Vanilla TL it could be deemed a user error (though there was no warning whatsoever when I installed it as root) but for distro packages the user doesn't have much of a choice. It needs to be fixed.

Comment: Reported at [TeXLive](http://tug.org/pipermail/tex-live/2016-August/039144.html) and at [`luaotfload` tracker](https://github.com/lualatex/luaotfload/issues/375).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A workaround was given by Akira Kakuto *via* the texlive mailing list:

> The current value of `TEXMFCACHE` in
>   `/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/web2c/texmf.cnf` and
>   `/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/web2c/texmfcnf.lua` is `TEXMFCACHE
>   = $TEXMFSYSVAR;$TEXMFVAR`
>
> You [can] set `TEXMFCACHE = $TEXMFVAR` in your own `texmf.cnf` and
>   `texmfcnf.lua` in, for example,
>   `/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/web2c/`.

But according to Karl Berry, this is not a TeXLive issue.

[Phillip Gesang issued a patch to `luaotfload`](https://github.com/lualatex/luaotfload/issues/375) that should fix the issue upstream.